# Implementing summation under combinatorial restriction

Tags: summation, combinatorics

For $m,n\in\mathbb N$, I am interested in the numerical evaluation of
$$f(m,n) = \sum_{s_j\in\{\pm1\}}' \prod_{k=1}^{2n-1} (1-e^{\frac{2i\pi}{m} s_k(s_{k+1}+s_{k+2}+\cdots+s_{2n})}),$$
where the summation is taken over $s_1, \ldots, s_{2n}\in\{\pm1\}$, with the additional assumption that exactly $n$ elements in $s_1,\ldots, s_{2n}$ are $+1$. For example, if $n=2$ the allowed $s_1,\ldots, s_4$ is
$$(s_1,\ldots, s_4) = (+1, +1, -1, -1), (+1, -1, +1, -1), (+1, -1, -1, +1), (-1, +1, +1, -1), (-1, +1, -1, +1), (-1, -1, +1, +1).$$
The $'$ in the summation denotes the restricted summation.

How can I implement this summation over restriction in Mathematica as a function of $m,n$?

```
f[m_, n_] := ???
```

For $n=1$, one may evaluate
$$f(m,1) = \sum_{s_j\in\{\pm1\}}' (1-e^{\frac{2i\pi}{m}s_1s_2}) = 2(1-e^{-\frac{2i\pi}{m}}).$$

Comment: Could you please show a concrete example for a small $ n $, say, $ n = 2 $ or $ n = 3 $?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ I put an example for $n=1$. Already for $n=2$, the evaluation by hand is too complicated.

Comment: notation you are using is very confusing. First what is $'$ in there mean? why do you have it? what exactly is the sum over? and is the $i$ in the $e^{2 i \pi}$ meant to the complex $i$ or an index?  What does your $f(1,1)$ for example supposed to generate?  What is the set $s_i$ looks like for say $n=2$?  is it $s=\{1,-1,1,-1\}$ ? or something else? if you clear these, may be will provide code but do not want to do as it is not clear to me now.

Comment: @Nasser Sorry if it was unclear. I modified the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this `f` what you desire:

```
Clear[f]
f[m_, n_] := Module[{s, summant, indexes},
  s[i_] := ToExpression@StringTemplate["s``"][i];
  summant = 
   Evaluate[Array[s, 2 n]] \[Function] 
    Evaluate@
     Product[1 - Exp[2 I π s[k] Sum[s[i], {i, k + 1, 2 n}]/m], {k,
        2 n - 1}];
  indexes = Permutations[Flatten@ConstantArray[{1, -1}, n]];
  Total[summant @@@ indexes]
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! However, I obtained an error when copy-pasting your code. (Please see my edited question.)

Comment: @eigenvalue I guess your version can not use `|->`? If yes, replace it with `\[Function].`

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot!
The trick `Permutations[Flatten@ConstantArray[{1, -1}, n]]` was very useful, and I should remember that.

Comment: @eigenvalue Glad to be helpful. This is just a first-step implementation and I think there should be room for speed- or RAM-optimizations, if for a larger  $ n $.